# document.ready not firing after passing a variable with xslt

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Greetings!
I have edited the question to properly explain the situation --

I have an XML file, and two XSLT files, namely students.xml, studentinfo.xslt and courses.xslt.

```
    <students>
     <student>
       <name>name1</name>
       <course id=001>course1</course>
     </student>
    <student>
```

studentinfo.xslt transforms students.xml into a styled html document, using jQuery tabs to display the info -- no problems here. This also sends a variable (id) to the second xslt document (courses.xslt) which displays the course information for that specific course id.

courses.xslt displays the specific course information for the course id sent from studentinfo.xslt. This html document once again is using jQuery tabs, to display the info. In this xslt, the document.ready() does not fire when the page is loaded, it only triggers once the page is refreshed. This only happens in IE, and is fine in firefox.

I have obviously simplified the xml, and retained the names to give a clearer idea of what I am trying to achieve.

I have tried using properly closed script tags, shifting the script tags to the bottom of the page, adding a setTimeout variable, and tried the window.load() function to no avail.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: How are you applying the XSLT templates to the XML file, exactly? It's quite hard to tell how you're doing things. Can you perhaps post a small complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: formulating a response now, will edit this once i finish.

Comment: I have updated the original question to properly reflect what I am doing.

Comment: This is a Javascript question -- not an XSLT question at all. Please, re-tag.

Comment: apologies, I have retagged it

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the processing model seems confused.

The XSLT transformation generates an HTML document. This generated document may contain Javascript. No Javascript is executed until the transformation is complete; it is then executed in exactly the same way as if the HTML document had been loaded directly from the server rather than being generated using XSLT.

Comment: Greetings,
The transformed HTML document triggers the event with no problems. I have a second template which accepts a variable from the first, and will display information specific to a child node. In this second template, the document.load() event does not seem to trigger / triggers to early, until the page is refreshed, and this happens only in IE.